# Android: Centering text in a textview when texview is centered in a layout

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

I need the text to be in the direct center of the screen, and want the textview to fill the parent. but it keeps aligning the start of the text to the center of the screen.

**How do i center the text in the middle of the screen when using a textview in android?**

this is what i have

[image: What iv got]

this is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  //removing this line has no effect
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**-------------------------------------**

[image]

Comment: PS: note that i do make use of `android:gravity="center"` so please do NOT call this a dup of anything that gives that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use a `RelativeLayout` here your solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use a `LinearLayout` if you want:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: plase see my second pic for a copy paste result of your first answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save the file activity_main.xml* first to see the changes(CTRL + S) it isn't saved, second the layout is how it would look on Nexus one, you better create separate layout-folders for 600dp+. Third there's some error I can see on your console please eradicate it, If nothing works clean your project and restart your eclipse I guess it would work